# Linking boost libraries in makefile under cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, linker, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to link my program with boost libraries using makefile with cygwin. Here is my makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wno-signed-compare -Wall -std=c++11 -funsigned-char -I /cygdrive/e/boost/include/boost-1_55/boost 
LNKFLAGS = -L cygdrive/e/boost/lib

SRCDIR = src
OUTDIR = bin

EXEC = $(OUTDIR)/prg
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OUTDIR)/%.o)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LNKFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) -l boost_thread

$(OBJECTS): $(OUTDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -O3 $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OUTDIR)

.PHONY: clean
```

Result:

```
$ make  
g++ -L cygdrive/e/boost/lib bin/test.o -o bin/prg -l boost_thread
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_thread
```

What's wrong? What should I specify?

Comment: How did you build you boost libraries ? Do you see any `libboost_thread-xxx` library ?

Comment: I have libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_55.lib and libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib in E:\boost\lib

Comment: Looks like those are build using Microsoft Visual Studio, but you're linking for other.

Comment: Still not answered, no windows boost users? I am using boost 1.64 on win7, cygwin g++ 5.4 x64, same error. my g++ flags are  -I c:/tools/boost/boost164/ and -Lc:/tools/boost/boost164/libs and I can see C:/tools/boost/boost164/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a; I installed boost1.64.7z  with C:\tools\boost\boost164>  bootstrap.sh gcc && b2.exe  .. failed 58, updated 1123 targets.

Comment: @mosh Your `-L` option should be `-LC:\tools\boost\boost164\stage\lib` at least.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Makefile the library search path is relative, but should be absolute in this case.

   ```
   LNKFLAGS = -L/cygdrive/e/boost/lib
   ```
2. Check if `/cygdrive/e/boost/lib` really contains Boost libraries built with the GCC toolchain.

   - `libboost_thread.a` or `libboost_thread.so` will work.
   - Libraries built with the Visual C++ toolchain ending with `.lib` or `.dll` will not work.
3. Check if the filename matches.

   - `-lboost_thread` requires that the library is named either `libboost_thread.a` or `libboost_thread.so`.
   - `libboost_thread-mt.a` or the like will not work.
4. You may find my [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53217345/3038842) helpful.